# Игнорирует if в C++

Tags: c++, mingw

Использую MinGW в QtCreator.
Игнорирует

```
if(sourceRow->size() > finalRow->size())
```

и всегда выполняет строку

```
directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));
```

код:

```
void Widget::conversion()
{
std::vector<std::pair<int, Direction> > directions; // rowNumber and direction
sourcePointsType::iterator sourceRow = m_sourcePoints.begin();
finalPointsType::iterator finalRow = m_finalPoints.begin();
int currentRow = 0;
for(;
    sourceRow != m_sourcePoints.end() && finalRow != m_finalPoints.end();
    ++sourceRow, ++finalRow, ++currentRow) {
    if(countPointsInRows(m_sourcePoints.begin(), sourceRow) ==
            countPointsInRows(m_finalPoints.begin(), finalRow)) {
        if(sourceRow->size() > finalRow->size()) {
            directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));
        }
    }
    else if(countPointsInRows(m_sourcePoints.begin(), sourceRow) >
            countPointsInRows(m_finalPoints.begin(), finalRow)) {
        directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));
    }
    else { // <
        directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Up));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Единственная причина по которой выполняется строка directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));
 - это истинность условия. Значит sourceRow->size() действительно всегда больше чем finalRow->size()

Comment: а если написать 
     if(5 > 6) { ваша функция; }
всё хорошо будет?
в QtCreator вроде отладчик есть, если я не ошибаюсь. Посмотрите, какие значения принимают ваши переменные во время проверки условия...

Comment: 5 > 6 - условие ложно)

Comment: Принимают значения правильные. При if(5>6) после выполнения строчки int b = 6; сразу перекидывает в начало блока. А при if(6>5) после int b =6; переходит сразу к строчку directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));. Я так понимаю компилятор оптимизирует так, т.е. при 5>6 выкидывает код, т.к. он не будет никогда выполняться, а при 6>5 всегда будет выполняться код.

Comment: @chevchelios: попробуйте запустить ваш код в Debug-режиме, без оптимизаций. Вполне возможно, что оптимизатор переписал код так, что первое и второе использование `directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));` "склеено" в одно.

Comment: Если Вы подозреваете оптимизатор, что он выкинул какие-то вещи, которые следовало бы оставить, так скажите компилятору, чтобы убрал свои грязные лапы от таких-то и таких-то переменных. Волшебное слово пишется volatile.

Comment: Похоже действительно дело в оптимизаторе. Добавил после directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down)); строку int a = 5; и теперь при ложном условии только эту строку и выполняет. Когда полностью проверю этот код, отпишу.

Comment: alexlz, если перед объявлением directions поставить volatile, то компилятор ругается на все push_back'и.

   error: passing 'volatile std::vector<std::pair<int, Direction>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, Direction> > >' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::pair<int, Direction>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, Direction> >]' discards qualifiers

Comment: Debug-режимом пользуюсь, иначе бы не узнал об этом. Программа не многопоточная.

Comment: Я вообще-то думал про sourceRow и finalRow (от них же зависит if). Но не видя текста... Ваши подозрения на оптимизатор могут быть верны, если кто-то из callback'ов меняет глобальные переменные, а оптимизатор этого не учитывает. Такие переменные и следует описывать как "изменяемые" (в смысле "независимо от данного кода")

Comment: @alexlz: оптимизатор не имеет права оптимизировать, если он не может _доказать_, что callback ничего не меняет. Изменения в семантике разрешены только для конструкторов копирования (их можно выбрасывать без предупреждения).

Comment: @VladD Откуда сведения?

Comment: @alexlz: это [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). По поводу того, что другие изменения запрещены, [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects.

Comment: @VladD "Пропуск копирования -- единственная разрешённая форма оптимизации, могущая изменять видимые побочные эффекты". Хм. А если в другом потоке? Да и в одном потоке при event-driven программировании много-то не нахулиганишь.

Да, а про итераторы я зря. Они-то никак не глобальные.

Comment: @alexlz: А насчёт другого потока, то несинхронизированный доступ -- вообще undefined behaviour. Компилятор имеет право сделать что угодно. И [некоторые](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) делают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил объединением двух условий в одно:

```
void Widget::conversion()
{
std::vector<std::pair<int, Direction> > directions; // rowNumber and direction
sourcePointsType::iterator sourceRow = m_sourcePoints.begin();
finalPointsType::iterator finalRow = m_finalPoints.begin();
for(int currentRow = 0;
    sourceRow != m_sourcePoints.end() && finalRow != m_finalPoints.end();
    ++sourceRow, ++finalRow, ++currentRow) {
    int countPointsInSourceRows = countPointsInRows(m_sourcePoints.begin(), sourceRow);
    int countPointsInFinalRows = countPointsInRows(m_finalPoints.begin(), finalRow);
    if(countPointsInSourceRows == countPointsInFinalRows && sourceRow->size() > finalRow->size()
            || countPointsInSourceRows > countPointsInFinalRows) {
        directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Down));
    }
    else if(countPointsInSourceRows < countPointsInFinalRows){ // <
        directions.push_back(std::make_pair(currentRow, Up));
    }
}
```

}